# Android - When do I need to include xml version and android schema?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

When do I need to include the xml version and `xmlns:android` declarations such as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  ...
</merge>
```

It makes sense to include if the layout is a parent layout.  Is this needed for child layouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It makes sense to include if the layout is a parent layout.

Yes.

> Is this needed for child layouts?

No. You shouldn't set it to child views/layouts.

You have to declare the android namespace only once. This is done in the top-level parent layout like you already noticed.